How can I test file system outputs in a Docker container using Go when bind volumes are not supported by testcontainers-go?
I'm developing a CLI application in Go that generates AsciiDoc from source code files and inline comments. The app reads code files from the filesystem and writes the resulting AsciiDoc files to another folder on the filesystem. I distribute this app as a Docker image.
For testing, I want to use BDD with Godog, and as part of my tests, I need to spin up a Docker container with test data, run my app, and then make assertions on the generated AsciiDoc files.
I planned to use testcontainers-go for this purpose, but I'm running into an issue. I need to mount volumes to check the output files on the host filesystem after the container has finished running. Unfortunately, testcontainers-go does not support bind volumes as per their documentation.
Question: How can I test my application's filesystem output (AsciiDoc files) in this scenario? The tricky part seems to be that the container terminates after the command is done (which is the intended behavior). But I cannot check files inside a terminated container and I cannot extract files from a terminated container. This is why I would like to use bind mounts similar to docker run ... --volume some/path:some/path .... This way the container could terminate as intended and I can run assertions on the results.
Is there a way to achieve this with testcontainers-go? If not, what are some alternative approaches to test file outputs in Docker containers using Go?
Any guidance or alternative solutions would be appreciated. Thank you!

A CLI application whose principal function is to read and write local files tends to not be a good match for a container setup – the required sudo docker run --rm -v ... -u ... boilerplate options will probably be longer than your main application's command line.  Can you distribute a (maybe statically-linked) binary, instead of an isolated container image?

Yes and No. I use Go for my CLI app, so I could provide a binary. But all my other projects are released as Docker images. I am aware of the boilerplate (but this is not that much actually). The upside of publishing as a container image is, that I can use already established release pipelines. I can release the CLI app the same way I already use for all my other projects. This way DockerHub is the only platform I have to maintain. My infrastructure doesn't support another artifact repository like Artifactory (since this app would be the only usecase I do not plan to introduce another one).

I experimented with https://golang.testcontainers.org/features/docker_compose. This way I can use volume mounts. But I the command for container now becomes static. This too is an issue. This way I would need a dedicated container for each testcase which is statically configured in docker-compose.yml file(s). If it helps. this is the specification I want to implement as test: https://github.com/sommerfeld-io/source2adoc/blob/exclude-files-and-folders/components/test/acceptance-tests/specs/basic.feature

One more note on the Docker images. Binary distribution: I actually thought about this quite a lot as you can see here https://github.com/sommerfeld-io/source2adoc/issues/90

Testcontainers are good when you need a service running (in the container) to test your app. But in this case, I don't think you need testcontainers. You could simply write "normal" tests and run them from within Docker. Or is the reason of using testcontainers because you want to test not really the program, but the Docker image that you ship?

I want to test the artifact that I ship (= the Docker image). The Binary resides inside the container. I build my Docker image once. go test for unit tests and go build are part of my multistage build. There is no separate build for a binary. Only the Docker build. And afterwards I want to test the image. ... I am not sure if testcontainers are the way to go. Seems like testcontainers provide an environment ("manage the dependencies") for the actual testcase. But this could be done with plain docker compose. So testing my actual app with testcontainers should be viable too. Any thoughts?

I found a way ... testcontainers-go seems to not offer a confif for bind mounts. However it mentions the use of HostConfigModifier which in turn uses features from the Docker API. This way you can mount volumes into your container.
This is how I did it (I built a custom struct to ensure modularization).
func NewContainerUnderTest() ContainerUnderTest {
    return ContainerUnderTest{
        image:   determineDockerImageToUse(),
        cmd:     []string{},
        ctx:     context.Background(),
        volumes: []string{},
    }
}

//...

// CreateContainer configures and creates a container but does not start it. All config must be done
// here. To add volumes, use the `AddVolume` method.
func (c *ContainerUnderTest) CreateContainer() {
    c.req = testcontainers.ContainerRequest{
        Image:      c.image,
        Cmd:        c.cmd,
        WaitingFor: wait.ForExit(),
        HostConfigModifier: func(hostConfig *container.HostConfig) {
            hostConfig.Binds = c.volumes
        },
    }
}

// AddVolume add a configuration to mount a volume to the container request. The pathOnHost is
// mounted as source folder on the host and as target folder in the container keeping the paths
// the same.
func (c *ContainerUnderTest) AddVolume(pathOnHost string) error {
    mount := pathOnHost + ":" + pathOnHost
    c.volumes = append(c.volumes, mount)

    return nil
}

// ...

cut = NewContainerUnderTest()
cut.CreateContainer()
cut.MountVolume(pathOnHost)

